# C# Iterating over a dictionary passed as a generic

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

I am having trouble trying to iterate over a dictionary passed to a function as a generic.  For example, I have a function that loads data from a DB.

```
public T Load<T>(...)
```

This function can be called like so, with which I have no problems;

```
someclasstype data = Load<someclasstype>(...);

List<someclasstype> data = Load<List<someclasstype>>(...);
```

I've recently tried to extend this to be able to deal with dictionaries as well, and calling it like so:

```
Dictionary<long, someclasstype> data = Load<Dictionary<long, someclasstype>>(...)
```

I can load the data without a problem and store it in the dictionary no problem.

At this stage, the dictionary, with all its keyvaluepairs is stored in a variable called result, and I'm creating an IEnumerable with

```
IEnumerator resultIdx = ((IEnumerable)result).GetEnumerator();
if (!resultIdx.MoveNext())
    return (T)result;

object kvp = resultIdx.Current;
```

So far so good.  I can see the value of the key and the value of the value in a watch, or by mouseover on the kvp variable.

But I cannot figure out how to get the value part of the keyvaluepair from kvp.

```
// None of these work - I get compile time errors, unboxing errors, or invalid cast errors.
object item = ((KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>)kvp).Value;

object item = ((KeyValuePair<long, object>)kvp).Value;

object item = ((T)kvp).Value // Never had a hope for this, but desperation...
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Use Reflection ? `object key kvp.GetType().GetProperty("Key").GetValue(kvp);
object value kvp.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(kvp);`
Not very optimized, but can work...

Comment: Awesome, Thanks Dede... that works perfectly.  This function already makes heavy use of reflection, so Im not worried about that (speed that is).

Comment: The part with the enumerator, is this part of the function `Load<T>` or is it outside of `Load<T>`? Because if it is outside, why don't you use the exact `GetEnumerator` method provided by `Dictionary<Key,Value>` ?

Comment: @ckruczek - The part with the enumerator is inside the load function.  But Dede's answer provided the solution.

Comment: Ok, nevertheless Dede provided a answer, which probably worked, but is restricted to dictionary. What if you pass something different then a dictionary to the function? The reflection call will fail. So please don't tell me you conditionally ask for types in your function and decide what to do? I highly recommend to overthink your architecture and your function to provide a more robust and maintainable function design.

Comment: try adding `dynamic kvp = resultIdx.Current;` . Then you can use `kvp.Value`

Comment: @Ashley John - that works too. Nice.. now I wonder which one is faster... I'm going to have to go read up on dynamics now.

Comment: @ckruczek - It works for other types without a problem (List, HashSet, etc) - The code provided was very pared down, but Dictionary<,> was a special case because of the double parameter thing.

Comment: Ahh ok this was not clear by the provided code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding `dynamic kvp = resultIdx.Current;` . Then you can use `kvp.Value`

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the function into two functions like.

```
public T Load<T>(...)
//Or maybe public List<T> Load<T>(...)
```

and

```
public Dictionary<long, T> LoadD<T>(...)
```

Then you can cast result to `KeyValuePair<long, T>` in LoadD. You can call *Load* from *LoadD* to minimize code rewriting.

Comment: I wanted to avoid  public Dictionary<long, T> LoadD<T>(...) because the long (in this case) represents a primary key in the database.  This cant be guaranteed though, its entirely possible the primary key is some other type,  or combination of types.  I didn't want to write a whole stack of overloaded Load() functions.

Comment: @ThereandThat How about `Dictionary<T,K> LoadD<T,K>(...)` ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by Dede in comments:

"Use Reflection ?

```
object key kvp.GetType().GetProperty("Key").GetValue(kvp); 
object value kvp.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(kvp);
```

Not very optimized, but can work... – Dede 24"